# Django CMS - How to add multiple (zero or more) links on a model in admin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm fairly new to Django CMS, and I've inherited a website with these specs:

- Django 1.10.8
- Django CMS 3.4.5
- Python 2.7

Unfortunately, there is no option to upgrade at the moment. Also, please pardon if I the terminology wrong - I'd appreciate corrections.

I have a Staff app with models for `Staff` and `StaffTranslation` (etc), and I have a task to update the admin to allow adding one or more links to each `StaffTranslation`. However, I'm having trouble identifying the best way to do this, and what components to use.

I have identified the [djangocms-link](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link) plugin, which could be a possibility, but I can't find instructions on how to add multiple instances to a model or admin page. Also, the latest version requires Django 1.11, at minimum.

I have also found the [PageSmartLinkField](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/fields.html#cms.forms.fields.PageSmartLinkField) - which seems smart - but I haven't been able to discover how to integrate it with data for the `StaffTranslation` object or how to display it on the admin page for that object.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to structure this - it seems like a simple enough task, I think I am just missing a piece or two, of the puzzle.

The end purpose is to have zero-or-many links on a `StaffTranslation` (which has its own admin page), with the ability to add at least url and link text to each of them. It would be smart if there is some UI helper, allowing for easy selection of internal links, but a text field would be ok.

**EDIT: the StaffTranslation model**

```
class StaffTranslation(TimeStampedModel):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, related_name='translations')
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)

    specialist_work_title = HTMLField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)  # SpecialistWorkTitle
    description = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)  # PersonText                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    experience = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)  # Experience

    phone_office = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)  # OfficePhone
    phone_cell = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)  # CellPhone

    mentions = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)  # Mentions
    education = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)  # Education

    other_qualifications = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)  # OtherQualifications

    meta_title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)  # MetaTitle
    meta_keywords = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)  # MetaKeywords
    meta_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)  # MetaDescription

    legacy_data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = querysets.StaffTranslationQuerySet.as_manager()

    # I would like to add something here like links = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name='links') - so should I make a Link model and add as a many to many relation, and how do I integrate that into the admin?
```

I left out the functions defined on the model.

Again, it would be nice to upgrade, but that won't happen until the summer at the earliest, and this task has to be resolved now. :)

Comment: What is `StaffTranslation`? Can you share the model? If you want to add a number of links, it sounds like it'd be great for your model to have a `PlaceholderField` so that (link) plugins can be added via the structure view of CMS.

Comment: If possible use python3+ and django2+. Setup a virtual environment and work with that. Show the models, I doubt you need a plugin to solve this

Comment: @markwalker_ I added the model as an example. Mind giving me a hint to use the PlaceholderField or a link to a tutorial?

Comment: @peterretief the upgrade hasn't been approved and will not happen in the next six months. Although it would be nice... :)

Comment: @Calle If you've got 6 months to wait on go-ahead for upgrading Django 2.2 (LTS) will probably out so that'll actually be good timing.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution for you here will be a placeholder field so you can add CMS plugins like any other plugin, for each instance of this model. For example;

```
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField


class StaffTranslation(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    content = PlaceholderField(
        'staff_translation'
    )
```

Then in your detail view template you do `{% render_placeholder object.content %}` and it'll show a placeholder for that object like it would for placeholders in any standard page template.

You can obviously then add any CMS plugins, links or otherwise, and the'll render alongside the other attributes on your `StaffTranslation` instance.

The docs on this are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html